# Need Apache rewrite rule to change part of url

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have urls like this:

www.example.com/**index.php/category-5**/subcategory/page

I want to rewrite to:

www.example.com/**category**/subcategory/page

I.e. I want to remove the "index.php/" and also remove the "-5", but keep the rest.

I am in way over my head with Apache. I normally just write plain simple php code.

I tried this and it didn't work:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php/category-1/(.*)$ /category/($1) [NC]
```

Thanks

Also, please, if we could make it a permanent redirect that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use parenthesis in the replacement part:

RewriteRule ^index.php/category-1/(.*)$ /category/$1 [NC,R=301]

See:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions

and

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html

you could activate debug logs, I've always found this useful as RewriteRule are tricky:

```
RewriteLog "/path-to-log/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 4
```

Comment: Hmm, that's not doing anything