# How would you apply rewrite rules to redirect old link structure to new?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I had links on my site with this structure:

1. site.com/category/1/cat1name (can have dashes)
2. site.com/lessons/1/lesson1name (can have dashes)
3. site.com/exercise/1/exname (can have dashes)

I changed structure to

1. site.com/guitar-lessons/cat1name/1
2. site.com/guitar-lesson/lesson1name/1
3. site.com/guitar-lesson-ex/exname/1

I am using laravel and I know I can use routes to take care of this, but I want to use 301 redirects from old link structure to new.

I am not sure how one creates the proper RewriteRule to factor in the different url parts and the reordering.

Examples I have read all seem to have their nuances for very specific needs. Being new to RewriteRules, I am not sure how to construct the rule. For case 1 above I tried

```
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$/(.*)$ guitar-lessons/$2/$1 [NC,R=301]
```

But using this [htaccess tester](http://htaccess.mwl.be/) that doesn't produce a match.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I shouldn't have posted so quickly. I realized that I didn't need the $ symbol in the first part of the rule. I had seen [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15512476/need-apache-rewrite-rule-to-change-part-of-url) and thought I needed to use the '$'. Rule is working:

```
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)/(.*) guitar-lessons/$2/$1 [NC,R=301]
```